# Android button not resizing when put in table programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to change the size (specifically the height) of a button in an Android app where the button resides in a table and is created programmatically.  I have tried about 20 different approaches and failed miserably.  If I create a button outside the table, I can change the size without a problem, but as soon as it goes in a table, the height stays fixed even though I can change the width.

I have tried creating and using, LinearLayout params, ViewGroup layout params, TableLayout params, etc. and setting their heights either via that constructor (e.g WRAP_CONTENT) or using setHeight().  I have also tried simply calling button.setHeight(). I have changed settings in my xml manifest for the table as well. I have used pixel values and Dpi values. All of this has failed. Here is the basics of what I have so far (just showing a call to b.setHeight()):

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
row.setId(counter);

TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
t.setText("BLH  " + counter);
t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

//I have also tried table.getContext() in this constructor...
Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) 
{ 
      //blah blah blah
});

//Convert from pixels to Dpi
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int heightDp = (int) (33 * scale + 0.5f);
int widthDp = (int) (60 * scale + 0.5f);      
b.setText(R.string.removeButtonText);
b.setTextSize(12);
b.setTag(counter);
b.setHeight(heightDp);
b.setWidth(widthDp);           
b.setId(counter);

counter++;
row.addView(t);
row.addView(b);

// add the TableRow to the TableLayout
table.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

This correctly results in a button being placed in the table, but the height does not change no matter what values I use.  In my xml file, here is what the table declaration looks like:

```
<TableLayout
 android:id="@+id/myTable"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="20dp" 
 android:stretchColumns="0">
</TableLayout>
```

I have tried messing with stretchColumns and other settings here; again, to no avail.  Does anyone have any idea why I can't change the height of a button added to my table programmatically, but have no problems doing so outside the table? I am sure it is some setting or adjustment that I just haven't found.  Any help is appreciated as I am at my wits end.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my problem.  Turns out it was an ordering issue.  The problem is that I was setting the height before adding the button to the table.  This caused the button's LayoutParams to not have any parent as explained here: [ViewGroup.getLayoutParams()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams%28%29). Here is what I needed to do (basically, change height *after* adding the button to the table):

```
    table.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //now change the height so the buttons aren't so big...
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int heightDp = (int) (33 * scale + 0.5f);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = b.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = heightDp;
    b.setLayoutParams(params);
    b.requestLayout();
    table.requestLayout();
```

The last two lines were suggested above by Lawrence.  The table and button seemed to update without these. However, it seemed to me to be a good idea to update just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
int heightDp = (int) (33 * scale + 0.5f);
int widthDp = (int) (60 * scale + 0.5f); 
ViewGroup.LayoutParams bLp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(widthDp,heightDp);
b.setLayoutParams(bLp);
```

instead of

```
b.setHeight(heightDp);
b.setWidth(widthDp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply blessenm.  I have tried that before (and I tried it again, with your code snippet above, just to be sure) and, unfortunately, it does not work.  For some reason the buttons simply don't show up using that method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call [View.requestLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29), this is not done automatically every time you add/remove child views.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  It turns out I was trying to set the height at the wrong time.  I was setting it before adding it to the table so the LayoutParams of the button were null (it had no parent) and therefore changing the height had no affect.  I added your suggestion as well just to be sure everything updated afterward.  Much appreciated.  Below I will post my code in case someone else comes across this.